# Nestled Loop not Working to gather data from NOAA

Tags: r, noaa, rnoaa

I'm using the R package rnoaa(along with it required other packages) to gather historical weather data. I wrote this nestled loop to gather all the data sets but I keep getting errors when I run it. It seems to run for a second fine

The loop:

```
require('triebeard')
require('bindr')
require('colorspace')
require('mime')
require('curl')
require('openssl')
require('R6')
require('urltools')
require('httpcode')
require('stringr')
require('assertthat')
require('bindrcpp')
require('glue')
require('magrittr')
require('pkgconfig')
require('rlang')
require('Rcpp')
require('BH')
require('plogr')
require('purrr')
require('stringi')
require('tidyselect')
require('digest')
require('gtable')
require('plyr')
require('reshape2')
require('lazyeval')
require('RColorBrewer')
require('dichromat')
require('munsell')
require('labeling')
require('viridisLite')
require('data.table')
require('rjson')
require('httr')
require('crul')
require('lubridate')
require('dplyr')
require('tidyr')
require('ggplot2')
require('scales')
require('XML')
require('xml2')
require('jsonlite')
require('rappdirs')
require('gridExtra')
require('tibble')
require('isdparser')
require('geonames')
require('hoardr')
require('rnoaa')
install.package('ncdf4')

install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
install_github("rnoaa", "ropensci")
library(rnoaa)


list <- buoys(dataset='wlevel')
lid <- data.frame(list$id)
foo <- for(range in 1990:2017){
for(bid in lid){
bid_range <- buoy(dataset = 'wlevel', buoyid = bid, year = range)
bid.year.data <- data.frame(bid.year$data)
write.csv(bid.year.data, file='cwind/bid_range.csv')
} 
}
```

The response:

```
Using c1990.nc
Using 
Error: length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
```

It saves the first data-set but it does not apply the for in the file name it just names it bid_range.csv.

Comment: For `write.csv()` check your working directory, or try specifying the complete file path.

Comment: Also, don't name files with dots, use underscore or dash bid_year.csv or bid-year.csv

Comment: I made those changes and added a token key still not avail

Comment: *along with it required other packages*...for a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), include all relevant code including `library` lines and data inputs. And please make sure it can run on its own for us to reproduce.

Comment: This is the complete #Parfait thanks in advance for looking

Comment: If possible, delete your token in your post because it should not be revealed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message shows that there are no any data of a given station id in 1990. Because you were using for loop, once it gots an error, it stops.

Here I introduce the use of `tidyverse` to download the NOAA buoy data. A lot of the following functions are from the `purrr` package, which is part of the `tidyverse`.

```
# Load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(rnoaa)
```

**Step 1: Create a "Grid" containing all combination of id and year**

The `expand` function from `tidyr` can create the combination of different values.

```
data_list <- buoys(dataset = 'wlevel')

data_list2 <- data_list %>%
  select(id) %>%
  expand(id, year = 1990:2017)
```

**Step 2: Create a "safe" version that does not break when there is no data.
Also make this function suitable for the map2 function**

Because we will use `map2` to loop through all the combination of `id` and `year` using the `map2` function by its `.x` and `.y` argument. We modified the sequence of argument to create `buoy_modify`. We also use the `safely` function to create a `safe` version of `buoy_modify`. Now when it meets error, it will store the error message and moves to the next one rather than breaks.

```
# Modify the buoy function
buoy_modify <- function(buoyid, year, dataset, ...){
  buoy(dataset, buoyid = buoyid, year = year, ...)
}

# Creare a safe version of buoy_modify
buoy_safe <- safely(buoy_modify)
```

**Step 3: Apply the buoy_safe function**

```
wlevel_data <- map2(data_list2$id, data_list2$year, buoy_safe, dataset = "wlevel")

# Assign name for the element in the list based on id and year
names(wlevel_data) <- paste(data_list2$id, data_list2$year, sep = "_")
```

After this step, all the data were downloaded in `wlevel_data`. Each element in `wlevel_data` has two parts. `$result` shows the data if the download is successful, otherwise, it shows `NULL`. `$error` shows `NULL` if the download is successful, otherwise, it shows the error message.

**Step 4: Access the data**

`transpose` can turn a list "inside out". So now `wlevel_data2` has two elements: result and error. We can store these two and access the data.

```
# Turn the list "inside out"
wlevel_data2 <- transpose(wlevel_data)

# Get the error message
wlevel_error <- wlevel_data2$error

# Get he result
wlevel_result <-  wlevel_data2$result

# Remove NULL element in wlevel_result
wlevel_result2 <- wlevel_result[!map_lgl(wlevel_result, is.null)]
```